# ArcGIS url query using date parameter stopped working overnight

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-server

Until a few days ago, this query ran without problems:

`https://dhsgis.wi.gov/server/rest/services/DHS_COVID19/COVID19_WI_V2/MapServer/11/query?where=RptDt>='2022-05-01'&outFields=*&returnGeometry=false&outSR=4326&f=json`

Now it returns:

```
error   
    code            400
    extendedCode    -2147220985
    message         "Unable to complete operation."
    details         []
```

The URL without `RptDt` specification still works just fine:

`https://dhsgis.wi.gov/server/rest/services/DHS_COVID19/COVID19_WI_V2/MapServer/11/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=*&returnGeometry=false&outSR=4326&f=json`

[Here is a link to the open data portal resource.](https://data.dhsgis.wi.gov/datasets/wi-dhs::covid-19-historical-data-by-state-v2/about)

The trouble appears to be in this bit: `where=RptDt>='2022-05-01'`.

Did ArcGIS change the formatting for date values? Does anyone know how I can update my URL to work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the date query to use a standardized date format it seems to work fine, ie using `RptDt>=date'2022-05-01'` instead of `RptDt>='2022-05-01'`.

Updated example URL: https://dhsgis.wi.gov/server/rest/services/DHS_COVID19/COVID19_WI_V2/MapServer/11/query?where=RptDt%3E=date%272022-05-01%27&outFields=*&returnGeometry=false&outSR=4326&f=json

Comment: If you happen to be using a datetime instead of a date, use `timestamp` instead of `date` as mentioned above, and make sure your datetime is formatted correctly. See <https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/api-rest/data-management/querying-feature-services-date-time-queries/> for more details.